# How can you combine two firebase observation results into the same array

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two nodes in my firebase DB that tracks like and comment notifications. Each value is parsed as a Notification class and I am looking to be able to get the snapshots from each node and create a merged notification array. The two functions I have work to pull the respective data but I dont know how to merge the two arrays. I tried to use sets and then form a union but I cant do it with non hashable values. The only other solution I could think of was to combine the two functions into one, however, this seemed and looked very wrong. Here is what Im working with...

```
var commentNotifications = [Notifications]()
func commentNotificationObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
    commentHandle = CURRENT_USER_COMMENT_NOTIFICATION.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.commentNotifications.removeAll()
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let id = child.key
            let dict = child.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            let notif: Notifications = Notifications(notifID: id, data: dict)
            self.commentNotifications.insert(notif, at: 0)
            update()
        }
        if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
            update()
        }
    })
}


// Detects New Likes
var notifications = [Notifications]()
func likeNotificationObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
   likesHandle = CURRENT_USER_LIKE_NOTIFICATION.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.notifications.removeAll()
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            for dictionary in child.value as! Dictionary<String, Any> {
                let id = dictionary.key
                let dict = dictionary.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                let notif: Notifications = Notifications(notifID: id, data: dict)
                self.notifications.insert(notif, at: 0)
                update()
            }
        }
        if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
            update()
        }

    })
}
```

So as you can see I have a **notifications** array and a **commentNotification** array. How can I get these into the same array without duplicates. Thanks!